# How do I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin.forms

How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity in Xamarin.Forms?

- In the main startup project, MyApp.Droid, I have **MyActivity.cs.**
- In the PCL project, MyApp.Plugin.Android, I have a non-activity class, **MyClass.cs.**
- In MyClass.cs I need to run some code in MyActivity.cs.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

---

**MyActivity.cs:**

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    // [Working Code...]
}
```

**MyClass.cs:**

```
public void OnSuccess
{
    // What should I put here to call MyMethod?
}
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to call another method that is within a different class? And are both these files within the same project?

Comment: @Symon: Yes. But they're in different projects. The Activity class is in the main Android project, and the utility class is in PCL. I need PCL to call the Activity's method.

Comment: You should be able to add a reference from project to project :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We already have a reference, but it's the other way... Main App has a reference to the Plugin. But I need the Plugin to access the Main app.

Comment: References are one way. If you want the Plugin to reference the main app, add the Main app reference to the the plugin

Comment: What type of class is MyClass.cs? is that class a service or handle broadcasts? is there any reason for starting an activity from a non activity class?

Comment: @Symon: It won't let me. It's complaining about circular dependency.

Comment: @RedM: It creates a WebRTC stream to the client. We need to create a Notification. (I thought that code could only be called from an Activity?).

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick! (I think, it been a while...)

MyClass.cs:

```
using System;

namespace MyClass {

   public static class Program {

     public static void MyMethod()
     {
         // [Working Code...]
     }

   }

}
```

MyActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using MyClass; //get your other file by the namespace

namespace MyActivity {

   public static class Program {

     public static void OnSuccess()
     {
         Program.MyMethod();  //[class name]..MyMethod();
     }

   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I guess MyClass would want to call "MyActivity.MyMethod()," or "Program.MyMethod()?" But MyClass does not have vision of MyActivity...